# Django - Function with template returns `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, orm, format

I am trying to use PostgreSQL's FORMAT function in Django to format phone number strings.

I can accomplish this with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
       phone_number, FORMAT('(%s) %s-%s', SUBSTRING(phone_number,3,3), SUBSTRING(phone_number,6,3), SUBSTRING(phone_number,9,4))
FROM core_user
WHERE phone_number iS NOT NULL
```

which returns a result like:

[image]

Trying to implement this into Django to be used for an ORM query, I did the following:

```
class FormatPhoneNumber(Func):
    function = "FORMAT"
    template = "%(function)s('(%s) %s-%s', SUBSTRING(%(expressions)s,3,3), SUBSTRING(%(expressions)s,6,3), SUBSTRING(%(expressions)s,9,4))"
```

ORM query:

```
User.objects.annotate(phone_number2=FormatPhoneNumber(f"phone_number"))
```

Returns the following error:

```
File /venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py:802, in Func.as_sql(self, compiler, connection, function, template, arg_joiner, **extra_context)
    800 arg_joiner = arg_joiner or data.get("arg_joiner", self.arg_joiner)
    801 data["expressions"] = data["field"] = arg_joiner.join(sql_parts)
--> 802 return template % data, params

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I believe it is due to this line `'(%s) %s-%s'` that is supplied to the FORMAT function.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use two consecutive percentages to produce a percentage after formatting, so:

```
class FormatPhoneNumber(Func):
    function = "FORMAT"
    template = "%(function)s('(%%s) %%s-%%s', SUBSTRING(%(expressions)s,3,3), SUBSTRING(%(expressions)s,6,3), SUBSTRING(%(expressions)s,9,4))"
```

But normally formatting is *not* done by the database, normally you do this in the model, in a model field, or in the view or template.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The task at hand is to actually push the formatting to the database. The output is not contained in the field, model, or view but rather a mail merge that is generated through a management command. I thought I tried this. Let me see if I have any success.

Comment: @Rory-R-Reyes: well I would strongly advise against pushing formatting to the database. Databases are *not* meant for this.

Comment: I got the same error using two consecutive percentages. I looked in django\db\models\sql\query.py and found that it was producing the SQL  I was looking for on [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/dcebc5da4831d2982b26d00a9480ad538b5c5acf/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L285) line, but also erroring out with the same error as I listed in the original question

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the solution using the FORMAT function to work, but I did get this to work with REGEXP_REPLACE which gives the same output:

```
class FormatPhoneNumber2(Func):
    function = "REGEXP_REPLACE"
    template = "%(function)s(SUBSTRING(%(expressions)s,3,10), '(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})', '(\\1) \\2-\\3')"


In [27]: result = (
    ...:     User.objects.filter(phone_number__isnull=False)
    ...:     .annotate(phone_number2=FormatPhoneNumber2("phone_number"))
    ...:     .values_list("phone_number", "phone_number2")
    ...: )

In [28]: for user in result:
    ...:     print(user)
('+16502553199', '(650) 255-3199')
('+12147047099', '(214) 704-7099')
('+12147547099', '(214) 754-7099')
```